# How I determine the number of units of input and the number of units of output TwoLayerQNN?

Tags: qiskit

I have 2 Linear layers: nn.Linear(64, 10) and nn.Linear(5, 2). I want to add TwoLayerQNN between these 2 linear layers above. How can I set up properly? I saw this example but something is not explained.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`TwoLayerQNN` is a Two Layer Quantum Neural Network consisting of a feature map, a ansatz, and an observable.
You need to use `CircuitQNN` instead, where you can modify `output_shape` parameters

Take a look at these two example, hope it helps you:

- https://qiita.com/DeepRecommend/items/7a28f2e96ef165a0ed1d#dense-parity-probabilities
- https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/01_neural_networks.html#4.1-Output:-sparse-integer-probabilities